# VS Code - Only one cpp file from a project compiles

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio-code

Okay so i have an error when am trying to run/compile the code.
Am guessing the problem is that my folder is not recognised as a project folder (i do not know how to solve that) and it compiles only one cpp file when it is needed to compile two of them.

error:

undefined reference to `Test2::fun()'

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

class.h

```
#include <iostream>

class Test2
{
public:
    int a = 25;
    void fun();
};
```

class.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "class.h"

void Test2::fun()
{
    std::cout << a;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "class.h"

int main()
{
    Test2 e;
    e.fun();
}
```

am not sure but that could be helpful to include my json files so... will include them

launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

tasks.json

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

I am new into vs code, sorry if that is a pretty easy to solve problem but am trying to figure it out and i can not.
As i said am thinking that vs code does not recognise it as a project and runs only main.cpp cause the error looks like that when am trying to run the code.
I was trying to run same thing on codeblocks and visualstudio2019 and it was working corretly so there is a problem with my vs code set up i guess.

Thanks for help and have a goood day <3

Comment: where do you think VSC is an IDE? In short it is NOT. Use CMake

Comment: Okay - First of all! I have not tought about VS Code as an ready to go IDE -  that is why i have posted the question. Despite of that you helped me a lot - CMake was everything i needed, thanks to you and see ya!